# want to improve my view

Tags: django, django-views

I've view like this. It worked. I'm new to django. Can you please help me to improve this code? thank you

```
def getAPI(request):
    username = request.GET.get('username')
    password = request.GET.get('password')
    #TODO Match user and password
    if username:
        user = User.objects.get(username__exact=username)
        is_exist = user.check_password(password)
        if is_exist == True:
            api_key = ApiKey.objects.get(id=user.id)
        else:
            error_message = 'username or password is invalid.'
    return render_to_response('details.html',locals(),
                        context_instance=RequestContext(request)
                        )
```

if username and password does not exist Then I want to print `error message`. Otherwise I want to print `ApiKey`. thanks

Comment: FWIW, you should *never* send a password via GET. The method on your form should be "post", and then you'd access the fields through `request.POST.get('field')`, or in the scenario of something like an API, like this, the client should be responsible for sending the request as a POST rather than a GET. Attempting to request via GET should result in an API error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the basic template to authenticate a user:

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate

def my_view(request):
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            # User is authenticated - return api key
        else:
            # Return a 'disabled account' error message
    else:
        # Return an 'invalid login' error message.
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean "print" (in which case just use python's print function) or do you want to return it in the response? If the latter, read up about django templates and passing variables to render_to_response.

Also, sticking a password as a GET variable is a bit of a bad idea, since it'll be visible on the URL:

http://example.com/whatever?username=me&password=s3cr3t

User/pass info should normally be sent via POST from a form. But maybe you're not that bothered about security.

Comment: I want to return it in response.